# Deeply rooted selenium web element Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get access to the title deep within an element. Here is an image of the html code

[image]

I want the text located in the highlighted section. Here is the code I thought would do this...

```
       element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='result_" + i+ " span[//class[span[//data-attribute]]]"));
        String tmpTitle = element.getText();
        System.out.println(tmpTitle);
```

But i am getting NoSuchElementException.. Can someone help me figure out how to get the highlighted text? Thanks!

Comment: Could you precise which text do you actually want to retireve ? Is this a text : `data-attributte="ScanDisk 23GB 4 SDHC memory .......(label may change)"` ? Or `title="ScanDisk 23GB 4 SDHC memory .......(label may change)"` ?

Comment: @kordirko data-attribute

Comment: Please add the HTML text of the page and remove the picture. The picture is too hard to read and is not as useful as text. Pictures of code are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will return the `data-attribute` attribute from the h2 element for all the results on the page.

```
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=san+disk");
List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li[id^='result_'] h2"));
for (WebElement result : results)
{
    System.out.println(result.getAttribute("data-attribute"));
}
```